# Why is $B_\pi$ an invariant bilinear form on $\mathfrak{g}$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, bilinear-form, invariance

> **Definition:** Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra and $(\pi ,V)$ be a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V$. A bilinear form $B$ on $V$ is said to be invariant under $\pi$ if for any $x\in \mathfrak{g}$ and any $y,z\in V$, one has the following:$$B(\pi (x)y,z)+B(y,\pi (x)z)=0.$$

> Now let $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\pi$ be as above and let $V=\mathfrak{g}$. Consider the bilinear form $B_\pi$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ as follows:$$B_\pi (x,y)=\operatorname{Trace}(\pi (x)\pi (y)),\quad x,y\in \mathfrak{g}.$$

> **Claim:** $B_\pi$ is invariant under $\pi$.

> **Need:**$$\operatorname{Trace}(\pi (\pi (x)y)\pi (z))+\operatorname{Trace}(\pi (y)\pi (\pi (x)z))=0,\qquad \forall x,y,z\in \mathfrak{g}.$$

But I can't see why it has to be true. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hint: Trace is conjugacy-invariant.

Answer (score 2):

We have $B_{\rho}(x,y)={\rm tr} (\rho(x)\rho(y)) = {\rm tr} (\rho(y)\rho(x))=B_{\rho}(y,x)$. The form is  *ad-invariant* for the Lie bracket, because
we have
\begin{align*}
B_{\rho}([x,y],z) & = {\rm tr} (\rho([x,y])\rho(z)) \\
  & = {\rm tr}(\rho(x)\rho(y)\rho(z))-{\rm tr} (\rho(y)\rho(x)\rho(z)) \\
  & = {\rm tr}(\rho(y)\rho(z)\rho(x))-{\rm tr} (\rho(y)\rho(x)\rho(z)) \\
  & = {\rm tr}  (\rho(y) \rho ([z,x])) \\
  & = - B_{\rho}(y,[x,z]). 
\end{align*}
Since $V$ is invariant, we have $\rho(x)y\in V$, so that $\rho$ is not defined on $\rho(x)y\in V$, if not $V=\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: What you have proved is that $B_{\rho}$ is invariant under the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak g$; not invariant under $\rho.$

Comment: I have proved that $B_{\rho}$ is invariant under the adjoint representation on my own way before you posted it.

Comment: Please do it for $\rho.$ I have written down the identity as well in my post what needs to be shown. What is $\rho (\rho (x) y)\ $?

Comment: I have taken $V = \mathfrak g$ and $\pi$ a representation of $\mathfrak g$ onto itself. So everything makes sense here.

Comment: This is the definition of invariance under $\pi.$ Please have a look at the second paragraph carefully before arguing.

Comment: Then I don't see why it should hold, if it is not the adjoint representation. We need to use $\rho([x,y])=[\rho(x),\rho(y)]$.